# Переключение между вкладками Chrome, зная tabId этих вкладок

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Здравствуйте.

Хочу реализовать переключение между вкладками Google Chrome в своём расширении. Расширение уже узнаёт `id` вкладок и может их обновлять.

Возможно ли сделать переключение между необходимыми мне вкладками, зная их `tabId`?

[image: Вот так получается]

Comment: chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { highlighted: true }); пробовали?

Comment: Сейчас попробовал, необходимая мне вкладка получает фокус, но остальные вкладки становятся, как бы enabled=false. Нужно тестировать вечером дома, не скажется ли это на встраиваемые скрипты. Спасибо за этот ответ @Cheg, теперь знаю в какую сторону копать.

Comment: тогда попробуйте chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true });

Comment: Идеально, это то что нужно было. Ещё раз спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого используйте `updateProperties` в методе `.update()`:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true });
```